# Why can't I apply scheme to codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

I change my default.conf by

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Syntax_highlighting_custom_colour_themes

But when I want to change my scheme, it shows me

```
Loading lexer_vhdl
Loading lexer_xml
SpellChecker: Thesaurus files 
D:\CodeBlocks\share\codeblocks\SpellChecker\th_en_US.idx' not found!
```

And the color didn't change. I don't know what problem it is.